# Xamarin Navigation.PopAsync can't work.I write the code like official example

Tags: xamarin.forms

The app.cs:

```cs
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new App9.LoginPage());
}
```

The LoginPage.cs

```cs
public LoginPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new Page1(), this);
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

I write this like official example,but when I click the login button,the LoginPage can't remove.And when I click the login button another time,it throw a exception.
In the official example ,the code work well.
How can I do to make this work?

Comment: Add the `Exception` that you are getting to your question. Also what platform(s) are you getting the exception on?

Comment: The Exception is:System.ArgumentException: before must be in the pushed stack of the current context.I run this in a Android vm,Version is 6.0.